# Wiring thermostat for gas fireplace correctly

Tags: fireplace, heater, propane, gas-burner

Good day,

I'm attempting to wire a Skytech SKY-1001 TH thermostat to a Jotul GF 400 BV propane fireplace. I thought this would be an easy plug-and-play job but so far it has not been.

With the thermostat connected, the fireplace won't ignite with the receiver set to "on" or by pressing the "on" button on the remote, and I suspect I'm doing something wrong. I'm fairly sure this is a compatible 750 mv thermostat based on what I've read online.

This shows how it's normally wired without the remote (it works fine this way):

[image: without thermostat]

This is how I'm attaching the thermostat receiver wires:

[image: with thermostat]

I set the rocker switch to thermostat and it doesn't ignite from the receiver or remote. I put the receiver through learn mode and verified that the remote is connecting to it.

I didn't do the original install and don't know who did. It's possible the existing wiring is incorrect but functional. One thing I noticed is that the pre-existing wiring doesn't match what's shown in the thermostat manufacturer's video [here](https://youtu.be/dCBDLi0MQ3U?t=405).

This is a screenshot from the video:

[image: install video screenshot]

So, in the video it looks like the fireplace wires are connected to the TP and TH/TP terminals, whereas on my fireplace, the fireplace wires are connected to the TH/TP and TH terminals. I don't know why there is a difference or which way is correct.

What is likely to be the problem here? I think I'm probably missing something that would be obvious if I knew a little more. Thanks to anyone who can try to point me in the right direction.

Comment: is the remote talking to the receiver at all, are the batteries ok in the remote what are the dip switch position in the remote and reciver

Comment: Is there a manual button, can you turn it on manually ?

Comment: @rukes Yeah the remote and receiver are talking. I went through the learn mode and heard the expected beeps.

Comment: @RohitGupta There is a manual option with the remote but it was not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After messing around with this for a while, I ended up concluding that the preexisting wiring (not installed by me) is probably incorrect. Confusingly, it doesn't match the wiring diagram in the fireplace manual either.

Following a tip from another forum, I tested putting the rocker switch into thermostat mode and jumping the orange and yellow wires with a paperclip. That made the burner ignite. So, I connected the thermostat wires to the terminals with the orange and yellow wires, and this is working now.